# Does g_strdup return NULL on memory allocation failure?

Tags: api, memory-management, glib

The glib documentation lacks many important things that I think API documentation absolutely should include. For instance the entry for [g_malloc](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-malloc) says **nothing** about that it will crash upon memory allocation failure (in direct contrast to the behaviour of the standard `malloc`, which the name implies that it mimics). Only if you happen to notice that there also is a variant named [g_try_malloc](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-try-malloc) and read its description you will be informed that `g_try_malloc`

> Attempts to allocate n_bytes, and returns NULL on failure. Contrast
>   with g_malloc(), which aborts the program on failure.

Now for the question, glib have a function `g_strdup` which also does not mention anything about possibly returning NULL. I assume that it will not since it is implied that it will be using g_malloc internally. Will it?

Comment: The tone of this post is such that I considered voting to close, for being argumentative and unconstructive; perhaps you could make it a little less rant-ish and stick more to your question?

Comment: API design is difficult (http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design), but if something walks like a duck and talks like a duck but in fact is a pigeon, it is a severe failure to not document this fact in a easy accessible place (i.e. together with the function description and not on display somewhere else behind a <strike>tiger warning</strike> memory handling page").

Comment: I don't wish to debate API design or the placement of the warning. I agree that it could be better and I understand your frustration. I was objecting to your antagonistic tone, and the long rambling bit before you asked your actual question. Stack Overflow frowns upon these things. However, I did not vote to close your post. I didn't even downvote it. I assumed you were venting some frustration, which we all need to do from time to time, and asked you to edit it. This request still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation does say it, though. Check the introductory section to the ["Memory Allocation"](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#glib-Memory-Allocation.description) page in the GLib manual:

> If any call to allocate memory fails, the application is terminated. This also means that there is no need to check if the call succeeded.

This goes for any library call that allocates memory, and therefore for `g_strdup()` too.